# TypeError:ForeignKey(['app_label.model_name']) is invalid.First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a custom model in django. but when try to migrate , i get the error :
 `TypeError: ForeignKey(['custom_models.CustomUser']) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'` 
 I have tried everything mostly answers are related to foreign key but i did not use ay foreign key relation in models here is my code:
 models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser , BaseUserManager
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self , email , username , password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('this is not correct email.')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('this is not correct username.')
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            usename = username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self , email , username , password ):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            password = password
        )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.is_active=True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user





class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60 )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60 , verbose_name='email' , unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True , verbose_name='date joined')
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True , verbose_name='last login')
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hide_mail= models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = 'username'

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    def has_perm(self , perm , obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    def has_module_permission(self , app_label):
        return True
```

here is settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for custom_models project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-=hipnv(5-ogef&#e0fwmd+ng-**gf2i1(-j#&_0p03jk8$gbg8'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = [ 'custom_models.CustomUser' ]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core.custom_models' ,
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'custom_models.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'custom_models.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

i have also tried this in settings.py before:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_models.CustomUser'
```

but i got:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
custom_models.CustomUser: (auth.E001) 'REQUIRED_FIELDS' must be a list or tuple.
```

i have tried everything on internet please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: it says ```REQUIRED_FIELDS = 'username'``` must be a list or tuple. so you should have ```REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']```

Comment: thanks it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your answer is right in the error msg `'REQUIRED_FIELDS' must be a list or tuple.`

```
 USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
 REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked!

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal if the answer helped you consider marking it as right.